# C# active directory environment.username and userPrincipal.SamAccountName

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am working on active directory authentication for my website. It works fine with **environment.username** and it shows my user name on my machine. But the problem is when I deployed this code to other users machine it still shows my user name. 
I am really beating my head to understand the main difference between 
environment.username and **userPrincipal.SamAccountName** in this context. What is the best way to show current logged in users username on the website.

Comment: `Environment.UserName` is the name of the user running the program on the host machine, it has nothing to do with who logged into your app!

Comment: Since you are using AD, you should use the AD properties to fetch the logged in user details.

Comment: Ad properties means? Could you please add which option from the above.